# C# RestSharp PUT request not sending

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to send a PUT request to my API to edit one of my records in one of my tables. This woks fine with Postman and the swagger page. But somehow it doesn't send when I'm trying to do this with C#'s webclient. This is my code.

```
public static void putProductData(string model, Models.Product product)
    {
        //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        // create the communication to the model from the API.
        string apiposturl = apiurl;
        apiposturl += model;
        apiposturl += "/bewerken";

        var client = new RestClient("http://mayapi.net");
        var request = new RestRequest("/api/products/bewerken", Method.PUT);

        // Zet de headers voor de request.
        // Dit is bij alles hetzelfde met een multipart/form-data requeset.
        request.AddHeader("postman-token", "293a9ff3-e250-e688-e20d-5d16ea635597");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "token");
        request.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        // Vul de parameters met de waardes van heet model.
        request.AddParameter("productNaam", product.ProductNaam);
        request.AddParameter("productPrijs", product.ProductPrijs);
        request.AddParameter("productBeschrijving", product.ProductBeschrijving);
        request.AddParameter("productType", product.ProductType);
        request.AddParameter("productKorting", product.ProductKorting);
        request.AddParameter("productVoorraad", product.ProductVoorraad);
        request.AddParameter("productDirectLeverbaar", product.ProductDirectLeverbaar);
        request.AddFile("productAfbeelding", product.ProductAfbeelding); // Voeg hier het bestandspad in.
        request.AddParameter("productWinkel", product.ProductWinkel);


        //client.Execute(request);
        // Verstuur de request.
        //IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; ;
    }
```

The weird thing is that when I execute this that there's no PUT request in Fiddler, so I can't really debug it through Fiddler. This is one of the errors the response shows in the code with breakpoints:

> {"The request was aborted: The request was canceled."}

I read that this could be fixed with Connection: Keep-Alive, but this sadly doesn't work for me. Can anybody please help me out?

**EDIT**

I thought this might be some useful information. if I send a post request with RestSharp it actually works, but the PUT request doesn't

Comment: What is the error you get (not in fiddler, but when you actually execute the code)? You may also use Wireshark to have a look what goes actually on the line and compare that to what you are using in Postman.

Comment: Literally the error which I mentioned

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't read carefully enough. Did you look into your server code / logs to see if there was an error or reason for cancellation ?

Comment: If there were to be a cancellation by the server I would be able to see it in fiddler, the request doesn't even reach anything. Hence why I said that fiddler didn't show any. And if there were to be an error like 500 RestSharp would fill it in the response, according to the threads I read. So I don't think it would be of any use to read the server logs.

Comment: This leaves us with Wireshark. At least you can check if anything goes out on the line. If not, then it is something internal to your code (or RestSharp).

Comment: btw: Why do you add a Postman-Token header ? ... and two content-type headers?

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with WireShark. It's just the tool I use. You can of course use any tool that does the same job.

Comment: WireShark says segment not captured

Comment: And you just indirectly said that WiereShark probably does the exact same thing as Fiddler, so please, be a bit more clear

Comment: Search for issues relating to RestSharp's `AddFile` method causing aborts, you'll find lots of work-arounds and (hopefully) solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it had to do something with my updated models in the API. They guy working on this code forgot to update the fields to the updated model. This is the reason why it wouldn't send the data.